# Save Data into Sql accroding to Json

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

```
I have json i need to insert data into sql server according to json using c# Code thorugh ado.net or something....

the sample json is :
{
"barcode": "Hasim Marfatiya",
"checkbox": true,
"date": "2022-02-01",
"datetime": "2022-02-01 11:58",
"email": "hashim.marfatiya@ashapurasoftech.com",
"lookup1": "Option 1",
"lookup": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2",
"Option 3",
"Option 4"
],
"number": 100,
"phone": "+91 8200184545",
"pin": {
},
"radio": "option1",
"signature": "gridfs://registrationFiles/a2dd2bad-ca25-4909-b8b8-88160c004fbb",
"slider": 5,
"text": "Simple Text",
"textArea": "Simple Text Area",
"time": "12:18",
"location": "science city road, Sola, - 380060, Gujarat, India",
"file": "gridfs://registrationFiles/f5c5eb64-a4ac-4217-be72-aa02d8fcfe47",
"search": {
"id": "1",
"email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"identificador": "11111112A",
"nomICognoms": "Valeriano Castaño",
"pais": "ES",
"contracte": "SDN123456H"
},
"timeDifference": 0,
"subform": [
{
"text": "Hasim",
"lookup": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2",
"Option 3",
"Option 4"
],
"searchV1": {
"id": "1",
"email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"identificador": "11111111A",
"nomICognoms": "Valeriano Castaño",
"pais": "ES",
"servei": "SECAO"
},
"subformV2": [
{
"text": "Maharshi",
"lookup": [
"Option 2",
"Option 1"
],
"searchV2": {
"id": "2",
"email": "manuel.canton@motumtech.com",
"identificador": "99999018D",
"nomICognoms": "Manuel Cantón Infante",
"pais": "ES",
"servei": "SECAP"
}
},
{
"text": "Vasudev",
"lookup": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2"
],
"searchV2": {
"id": "3",
"email": "rdeblas@isigma.es",
"identificador": "46235239H",
"nomICognoms": "Roman de Blas",
"pais": "ES",
"servei": "SECAP"
}
}
]
},
{
"text": "Ravi",
"lookup": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2",
"Option 3",
"Option 4"
],
"searchV1": {
"id": "2",
"email": "manuel.canton@motumtech.com",
"identificador": "99999018D",
"nomICognoms": "Manuel Cantón Infante",
"pais": "ES",
"servei": "SECAP"
},
"subformV2": [
{
"text": "Nimesh Patel",
"lookup": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2"
],
"searchV2": {
"id": "4",
"email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"identificador": "99999999R",
"nomICognoms": "AAA Engineer",
"pais": "ES ",
"servei": "AAA"
}
}
]
}
]
}
```

so i need to create dynamically table structure as per above json and insert data into table as well

for example :
Table structure should be:

```
Table 1 => Widget_Test_Form => ParentTable
{
"RowId": "c7b079b9-561a-4292-88b0-5e66a1bc670b", //auto genrated Guid
"Barcode": "Hasim Marfatiya",
"Checkbox": true,
"Date": "2022-02-01",
"Datetime": "2022-02-01 11:58",
"Email": "hashim.marfatiya@ashapurasoftech.com",
"Lookup1": "Option 1",
"Lookup": "[\r\n \"Option 1\",\r\n \"Option 2\",\r\n \"Option 3\",\r\n \"Option 4\"\r\n]",
"Number": "100",
"Phone": "+91 8200184545",
"Pin": "{\r\n \"pins\": []\r\n}",
"Radio": "option1",
"RDW": " ",
"Signature": "gridfs://registrationFiles/a2dd2bad-ca25-4909-b8b8-88160c004fbb",
"Slider": "5",
"Text": "Simple Text",
"TextArea": "Simple Text Area",
"Time": "12:18",
"Calculation": " ",
"Location": "science city road, Sola, - 380060, Gujarat, India",
"File": "gridfs://registrationFiles/f5c5eb64-a4ac-4217-be72-aa02d8fcfe47",
"TimeDifference": "0"
}

Table 2 => Widget_Test_Form_Search => SubTable of Widget_TestForm
{
"RowId": "ffe5e58a-5f49-4bca-898b-3aabc1c4d555",
"Widget_Test_FormRawId": "c7b079b9-561a-4292-88b0-5e66a1bc670b", //foriegn Key of (Widget_Test_Form)
"Email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"Identificador": "11111112A",
"NomICognoms": "Valeriano Castaño",
"Pais": "ES",
"Contracte": "SDN123456H"
}


Table 3 => Widget_Test_Form_Subform => SubTable of Widget_TestForm

[
{
"RowId": "0da42b02-7f7e-4c01-b87d-de926787cb48",
"Widget_Test_FormRawId": "c7b079b9-561a-4292-88b0-5e66a1bc670b", //foriegn Key of (Widget_Test_Form)
"Text": "Hasim",
"Lookup": "Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,Option 4"
},
{
"RowId": "bfcd7cb6-65e1-4df8-9914-5635b6400ba2",
"Widget_Test_FormRawId": "c7b079b9-561a-4292-88b0-5e66a1bc670b", //foriegn Key of (Widget_Test_Form)
"Text": "Ravi",
"Lookup": "Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,Option 4"
}
]

Table 4 => Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SearchV1 => SubTable of Widget_Test_Form_Subform
[
{
"RowId": "e5032fdc-bc20-4f02-a523-22ca17d36baf",
"Widget_Test_Form_SubformRawId": "bfcd7cb6-65e1-4df8-9914-5635b6400ba2", //foriegn Key of (Widget_Test_Form_Subform)
"Email": "manuel.canton@motumtech.com",
"Identificador": "99999018D",
"NomICognoms": "Manuel Cantón Infante",
"Pais": "ES",
"Servei": "SECAP"
},
{
"RowId": "1f17cb6a-6725-424e-984d-afda92681b9d",
"Widget_Test_Form_SubformRawId": "0da42b02-7f7e-4c01-b87d-de926787cb48", //foriegn Key of (Widget_Test_Form_Subform)
"Email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"Identificador": "11111111A",
"NomICognoms": "Valeriano Castaño",
"Pais": "ES",
"Servei": "SECAO"
}
]

Table 5 => Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2 => SubTable of Widget_Test_Form_Subform
[
{
"RowId": "94565700-c4bf-4d9d-adf3-1a0409f213f4",
"Widget_Test_Form_SubformRawId": "0da42b02-7f7e-4c01-b87d-de926787cb48",
"Text": "Maharshi",
"Lookup": "Option 2,Option 1"
},
{
"RowId": "b972f55f-aac4-4b6e-8ade-634aad52a592",
"Widget_Test_Form_SubformRawId": "bfcd7cb6-65e1-4df8-9914-5635b6400ba2",
"Text": "Vasudev",
"Lookup": "Option 1,Option 2"
},
{
"RowId": "4f591f2d-4f94-4557-a8d7-738fda8868a1",
"Widget_Test_Form_SubformRawId": "bfcd7cb6-65e1-4df8-9914-5635b6400ba2",
"Text": "Nimesh Patel",
"Lookup": "Option 1,Option 2"
}
]

Table 6 => Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2_SearchV2 => sub table of Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2

[
{
"RowId": "2573fac9-2d7e-432c-a398-baa871025b13",
"Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2RawId": "b972f55f-aac4-4b6e-8ade-634aad52a592", //foriegn key of (Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2)
"Email": "rdeblas@isigma.es",
"Identificador": "46235239H",
"NomICognoms": "Roman de Blas",
"Pais": "ES",
"Servei": "SECAP"
},
{
"RowId": "3d5cfd5a-5601-4cc4-9dc3-0dc5e79a9478",
"Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2RawId": "94565700-c4bf-4d9d-adf3-1a0409f213f4", //foriegn key of (Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2)
"Email": "manuel.canton@motumtech.com",
"Identificador": "99999018D",
"NomICognoms": "Manuel Cantón Infante",
"Pais": "ES",
"Servei": "SECAP"
},
{
"RowId": "c2fb61bf-b78a-43ea-8168-a0091556dabd",
"Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2RawId": "4f591f2d-4f94-4557-a8d7-738fda8868a1", //foriegn key of (Widget_Test_Form_Subform_SubformV2)
"Email": "valeriano.castano@motumtech.com",
"Identificador": "99999999R",`enter code here`
"NomICognoms": "AAA Engineer",
"Pais": "ES ",
"Servei": "AAA"
}
]
```

1. I need to make tables in Sql Dynamically as per json forma.
2. And items must be enter in those tables as data.
3. Must Assign Foraign keys automatically.

Comment: Do you mean to save this data to database in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

you can extract Json string using   OPENJSON
for example

declare @txt_Tar as nvarchar(max)
set @txt_Tar='{"id":1,"text":"test"},{"id":2,"text":"test2"}'

set @txt_Tar='['+@txt_Tar+']'
insert into yourtable
(col1,col2)
select
a.id,a.[text] T1
from
OPENJSON (@txt_Tar)
WITH (id int,    [text] nvarchar(max)  )  a